# Laravel 5.4 css files not showing and showing NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-5, xampp, laravel-5.4

i have installed Laravel 5.4 in localhost. I'm using XAMPP to host the application. I'm using Laravel's inbuilt Blade template structure to show the data. I have used asset() helper to load my assets files which is inside the public folder. A sample code is here.

```
<link href="{{URL::asset('backend/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But CSS file is not loading. I discovered this from Chrome developer tool's Network section. I have worked with Laravel before with it's other version and this is the first time that i'm working with version 5.4. Hope someone will assist me to solve this.

Comment: Install 5.5 already.

Comment: put css in public or storage

Answer (score 1):

you can use only asset function like this i hope you have css folder inside public folder as mentioned in the path.

```
<link href="{{asset('backend/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**asset()**

Generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers

Comment: I used this method as well before. So i decided to try with mentioned way.

Comment: Nope it's also not working. But by using these both methods, i can see it generates correct url when i'm checking the Network section of the browser.

Comment: i think you dont have file inside public folder and mentioned path

Comment: It's inside public folder->assets folder and then my mentioned folders

Comment: if its asset folder then update like asset('asset/backend/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}

Comment: Sorry, i have included assets folder as well there.

Comment: can you move folders from asset to outside

Comment: Finally could able to solve the issue. It was a permission issue friend. Changed the permission to 777 and works fine.

Comment: better you can set permission to 755

Comment: Ok i will do that